# Find string without comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code where I find keys where the string values are separated by comma

```js
var db = {
     "name": "Nkosana",
     "middle": "Baryy",
     "surname": "walked",
     "batch_number": "test,b",
     "temp": ",,67,6,87,86,5,67865,876,67",
     "integrity": ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
     "weight": "760,765,755,758,759,758,758,769,758,762,759,7",
     "comment": "oh la la",
    };

for (var key in db) {
  if (db.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   if(db[key].indexOf(',')>-1){
       console.log(key+' | ' + db[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I can retrieve these values

```
batch_number | test,b
temp | ,,67,6,87,86,5,67865,876,67
integrity | ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
weight | 760,765,755,758,759,758,758,769,758,762,759,7
```

Now I would like to know how if there is a way I can retrieve **only** the keys of values that **do not have commas**

Comment: `if(db[key].indexOf(',')==-1){ ... }`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Please create this as answer.

Comment: oh my...........

Comment: @Jonathan Hmm, want me to repost? ;p

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yup!

Comment: @Jonathan Alright, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As I mentioned in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238348/find-string-without-comma?noredirect=1#comment77442526_45238348), the fix is simple. You just need to change the if condition a bit:

```
if(db[key].indexOf(',')==-1){ ... }
```

This is because [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns -1 when the search string is not present in the string to be searched.

The complete code listing is:

```js
var db = {
     "name": "Nkosana",
     "middle": "Baryy",
     "surname": "walked",
     "batch_number": "test,b",
     "temp": ",,67,6,87,86,5,67865,876,67",
     "integrity": ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
     "weight": "760,765,755,758,759,758,758,769,758,762,759,7",
     "comment": "oh la la",
    };

for (var key in db) {
  if (db.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   if(db[key].indexOf(',') == -1){
       console.log(key+' | ' + db[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `indexOf(',') > -1` to `indexOf(',') == -1`:

```js
var db = {
     "name": "Nkosana",
     "middle": "Baryy",
     "surname": "walked",
     "batch_number": "test,b",
     "temp": ",,67,6,87,86,5,67865,876,67",
     "integrity": ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
     "weight": "760,765,755,758,759,758,758,769,758,762,759,7",
     "comment": "oh la la",
    };

for (var key in db) {
  if (db.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   if(db[key].indexOf(',')==-1){
       console.log(key+' | ' + db[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var db = {
     "name": "Nkosana",
     "middle": "Baryy",
     "surname": "walked",
     "batch_number": "test,b",
     "temp": ",,67,6,87,86,5,67865,876,67",
     "integrity": ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
     "weight": "760,765,755,758,759,758,758,769,758,762,759,7",
     "comment": "oh la la",
    };

for (var key in db) {
  if (db.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   if(db[key].indexOf(',')==-1){
       console.log(key+' | ' + db[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change `if(db[key].indexOf(',')>-1)` to `if(db[key].indexOf(',') == -1)`.

Here's your updated code:

```
var db = {
        "name": "Nkosana",
        "middle": "Baryy",
        "surname": "walked",
        "batch_number": "test,b",
        "temp": ",,67,6,87,86,5,67865,876,67",
        "integrity": ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
        "weight": "760,765,755,758,759,758,758,769,758,762,759,7",
        "comment": "oh la la",
    };

for (var key in db) {
  if (db.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if(db[key].indexOf(',') == -1){
       console.log(key+' | ' + db[key]);
    }
  }
}
```